# ELK replication and the role of the Data Nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I'm running an ELK cluster with 3 Data nodes. 2 of the Data nodes are also used as data ingestion nodes using 2 logstash systems.

I'm running on 1 shard and 0 replicas for a single index, which is daily created with around 2 million documents per index. The current size of an index is around 8GB.

As I don't have many nodes, 1 shard would be enough for the index. I think.

However 0 replica means, there will be no replicas available. But as I'm using 1 shard, every index is located in a single node.

**Now my question is, is different indexes are stored in different data nodes, or all the data are stored in all the data nodes?**

Some time ago, One data node failed and I removed it physically and added a new node into the cluster. No data was lost according to my understanding.

do I need to change the replica to 1.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index is split into multiple shards that can be stored across multiple data nodes.

If an index has **one shard and zero replicas**, all its documents will be stored on one data node only. If this node fails, the entire index is lost.

If an index has **one shard and one replica**, ES usually puts them in different data nodes so that if one node fails, the index can be recovered from another node.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So. ..when im in with one shard and 0 replica, if i have 2 nodes, does both of them has the same data or two different set of data.  I had the experience of losing one node and according to my understanding the remaining node had almost all the data. So how does that happens if 2 nodes have different data sets ? Or have i lost data ?

Comment: If you have 2 data nodes and one shard for an index, all the data will be stored on one node. So you might have lost the data node without the shard.